# Set indexStack to 0 when back button is pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an **IndexStack** as the main way of navigation, however when the user tap on the back button, the Navigation goes back to the previous scaffold.

Currently im using a WillPopScope(), but i keep receiving an error saying...

> type '() => void' is not a subtype of type '() => Future'

This is the code.

NavPage.dart

```
class NavPages extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavPagesState createState() => _NavPagesState();
}

List<Widget> screens = new List();
List<String> site = new List();

class _NavPagesState extends State<NavPages> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    site.add('..............');
    return Consumer<User>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        screens.add(GotKeysSites(
          user: value,
          departmentClicked: (title) {
            if (title.isNotEmpty) {
              var pos = site.indexWhere((element) => element == title);
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = pos;  //Here the index is updated however, i receive the error commented above.
              });
            }
          },
          departmentCallback: (title, departmentsAssigned, startTime, endTime) {
            if (title.isNotEmpty && departmentsAssigned.isNotEmpty) {
              site.add(title);
            }
          },
        ));
        return Scaffold(
          body: IndexedStack(
            index: _selectedIndex,
            children: screens,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

typedef void ReturnIndex();
```

and the class where i call the **ReturnIndex Function**

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: widget.returnIndex,
      child: Scaffold(
      ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OnWillPop scope expects you to give it a proper function so try doing any one of these 2 changes
**CHANGE1**

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop:(){ 
         widget.returnIndex;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
      ));
```

OR
**CHANGE2**

```
void returnIndex(){//Future<void> if it is a future object
}
```

Comment: The second option solved the issue, Thank for your answer :)

Comment: @LuisCardozaBird welcome to stackoverflow. If the answer works you give it an upvote(Like you did) and also accept it as answer so that everyone knows what to follow

Comment: I know, it's just that i have to wait the 5 minutes jajajajaja

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but to add on to the above answer:
WillPopScope does indeed look for a future in response to onWillPop, so you'll need to take that into account as you define a(n async) function / assign a value of a Future.